# MySQL, SQL how to retrieve the full row containing less used value in a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, distinct

I have a nice trivial quiz for the weekend ... quite sorry it is even hard to type down the title.

**Context**
Let me do an example (`uuid` and `value` are *strings*):

```
Table1
---------------
uuid   | value
---------------
1      | x
1      | a
3      | z
2      | y
1      | x
1      | x
3      | b
```

This is the expected result

```
---------------
uuid   | value
---------------
1      | a
3      | z
3      | b
```

Because the above are the rows that contain for a given `uuid` the less common value (or equal) among the average values used.
I am playing with `GROUP BY`, `DISTINCT`, `COUNT`...

**Attempt ONE**

```
SELECT uuid, COUNT(uuid) as time_used, value
FROM table1
GROUP BY uuid, value ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

**Attempt TWO**

```
SELECT uuid, COUNT(uuid) as occ
FROM (
    SELECT uuid, COUNT(uuid) as occ, value
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY uuid, value ORDER BY COUNT(*)) as t
GROUP BY uuid;
```

**Attempt THREE**

```
SELECT uuid as occ
FROM (
    SELECT uuid, COUNT(uuid) as occ, value
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY uuid, value ORDER BY COUNT(*)) as t
GROUP BY uuid
HAVING COUNT(uuid) > 1;
```

But it is not the right one, I still miss a step...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/593a74/3

Note I am using MySQL, few data (around 2000) but still want to be 'performant', they will grow and I would like to be compliant with the `only_full_group_by` statement of MySQL.
Thanks.

Comment: Write a query to get the count grouped by uuid and value. Then use that as a subquery in a query that gets the rows with the minimum count grouped by uuid. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql for how to do the second part.

Comment: There is no MySQL 5.8, as far as I know.

Comment: let me fix the mysql version.. come on is the worst question I ever made on stackoverflow.. too tired sorry,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL versions prior to 8, you can generate the result you require by using a subquery to get the counts of each `uuid`/`value` combination, this is then used to get the minimum and total count value for each `uuid` and that result is then joined to another copy of the subquery to get the output:

```
SELECT c.uuid, c.value
FROM (
  SELECT uuid, MIN(cnt) AS min_cnt
  FROM (
    SELECT uuid, value, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY uuid, value
  ) c
  GROUP BY uuid
  HAVING SUM(cnt) > 1
) m
JOIN (
  SELECT uuid, value, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY uuid, value
) c ON c.uuid = m.uuid AND c.cnt = m.min_cnt
```

Output:

```
uuid    value
1       a
3       z
3       b
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/yJPVzjL7UzyfpeF5Dpzyf/1)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you would use window functions:

```
SELECT uv.*
FROM (SELECT uuid, COUNT(*) as cnt, value,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY uuid ORDER BY COUNT(*)) as seqnum
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY uuid, value 
     ) uv
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately i just gave a try but 0 rows are returned.